# List all combinations with replacement (but order matters) of all permutations of a list

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

Given an input list such as `[1, 2]`, I'd like to obtain a list of combinations of all the possible permutations of the input list. So something like:

List of permutations:
`[[1, 2], [2, 1]]`

List of combinations:

```
[[[1, 2], [1, 2]],
 [[1, 2], [2, 1]],
 [[2, 1], [1, 2]],
 [[2, 1], [2, 1]]]
```

Where the number of objects to choose is equal to the length of the original list (so 2 choices per combination)

I tried this using itertools:

```py
def generate_preferences(input_list):
    n = len(input_list)
    all_permutations = [list(p) for p in list(permutations(input_list, n))]
    all_combinations = [list(p) for p in list(combinations_with_replacement(all_permutations, n))]
    return all_combinations
```

But got the following result back:

```
[[[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]]]
```

And I'm not sure how to specify the order mattering, as my best guess is that the function is ignoring

`[[1, 2], [2, 1]]` vs `[[2, 1], [1, 2]]`

Comment: Sidenote: is there a reason you're converting tuples to lists? Seems like an unnecessary inefficiency

Comment: Not really, I still have to figure out the specific implementation but aiming to put these into a dictionary and the function that I need to run already uses those individual lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If order matters, you don't want combinations, you want the Cartesian product.

Replace `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
def generate_preferences(
    input_list: list[int]
) -> Iterator[tuple[tuple[int, ...], ...]]:
    n = len(input_list)
    all_permutations = itertools.permutations(input_list)
    return itertools.product(all_permutations, repeat=n)
```

Then

```
>>> list(generate_preferences([1, 2]))
```

outputs

```
[
    ((1, 2), (1, 2)), 
    ((1, 2), (2, 1)), 
    ((2, 1), (1, 2)), 
    ((2, 1), (2, 1)),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, was a bit of a brain fart forgetting the cartesian product lol